# Error incorrect usage of spatial/fulltext/hash index and explicit index order while running SQL script

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I run a SQL script for MySQL 8.0.12 on the Workbench as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE seminar2018.FILE (
  name                TEXT        NULL,
  fileobjectkey       VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  checksum            TEXT        NULL,
  keychecksum         TEXT        NULL,
  policy              TEXT        NULL,
  encryptedrawfilekey TEXT        NULL,
  ivfilekey           TEXT        NULL,
  trustedLocations    TEXT        NULL,
  accessrights        TEXT        NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (fileobjectkey),
  FULLTEXT INDEX policy_fulltext (policy ASC)
);
```

but when I run it gave me error like this

> Error Code: 1221. Incorrect usage of spatial/fulltext/hash index and
>   explicit index order

Is there something wrong with the script?

Comment: `FULLTEXT INDEX policy_fulltext (policy ASC)` is wierd iam assuming a FULLTEXT index does not have index direction like BTREE Indexing has... Use `FULLTEXT INDEX policy_fulltext (policy)` instead.

Comment: @RaymondNijland that fixes the problem! but still not sure why it gave error previously. does it have to do with the version of mysql? since when i run it in older version it doesn't return this problem

Comment: "does it have to do with the version of mysql? since when i run it in older version it doesn't return this problem" Older MySQL versions just ignonred  the index direction part.. MySQL 8.0+ actually uses it